# How to write rewrite rule to convert url to selector

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, aem

I have a url like below.
http://mywebsite.com/extractMe/test/id.html which needs to be converted as http://mywebsite.com/extractMe/test.id.html i.e the last ***/test/id.html*** to ***/test.id.html*** making the last word before extension as selector before the call to my server.

Comment: Any new update on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?extractMe/test\.([^/d]+)/?$ /extractMe/test/$1 [L,QSA]
```

not 100% sure if this will work. But seems like the only way to do it.
Just create a `.htaccess` file with these inputs.